# MySQL: Category Tree and Products in n levels

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, hierarchical-data

So, let's assume I've a MySQL DB with the following tables:

**Product**

- id
- name
- category_id

**Category**

- id
- name
- parent_id

What's the best way to query the DB in order to get all products going down from a certain category id. For instance, if I've a tree of sub-categories where the base category id = `1` how can I get all the products under the subcategories of id =`1` for an undetermined number of sub-categories.

I could do this:

```
SELECT * FROM `Product` WHERE category_id IN (
   SELECT `id` FROM `Category` WHERE parent_id = 1
)
```

However it only works for the direct children of category id = `1` and not for the 2nd to n level children.

Thank you.

---

**Edit**

Some people suggested to read [a blog article](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/) about this, I had a look at that article on the past also, and I made this sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/be72ec/1

As you can see on the query, even the simplest method they teach, to get a tree of categories doesn't output anything. What am I missing? The other methods have the same issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this article "Hierarchical data in MySQL: parents and children in one query": http://explainextended.com/2009/07/20/hierarchical-data-in-mysql-parents-and-children-in-one-query/ . I think it could answer your question.

Comment: @stefan I tried that posts on the past, but by some reason they don't return any data... And there's someone else on the comments also saying that he has the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your sqlfiddle and came to the following conclusion.

The problem with your code is, that you are using NULL values.
Look at this sqlfiddle to see a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07ef7/1/0

I did some corrections on your statements and now everything works.
Here is a list with the changes i did:

- Change "`parent_id` bigint(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL," to "`parent_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," within the create statement
- Remove the foreign key constraint, but i didn't get it working with "0" as parent_id
- Insert "0" instead of "NULL" as parent_id
- Change data typ INT to BIGINT within the FUNCTION, because you are using this type within your creation statement
- Remove the WHERE clause from the select statement

I hope that helps you!

Here are the statements, just in case sqlfiddle is not working right now:

```
CREATE TABLE `Category` (
  `id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `parent_id` (`parent_id`),
  KEY `ix_hierarchy_parent` (`parent_id`, `id`)
)//


INSERT INTO `Category` (`id`, `name`, `parent_id`)
VALUES
    (1,'Cat Name 1',0),
    (2,'Cat Name 2',0),
    (3,'Cat Name 3',2),
    (4,'Cat Name 4',2),
    (7,'Cat Name 5',4),
    (8,'Cat Name 6',4),
    (9,'Cat Name 7',4),
    (10,'Cat Name 8',4),
    (11,'Cat Name 9',4),
    (12,'Cat Name 10',4),
    (13,'Cat Name 11',2),
    (16,'Cat Name 12',13),
    (17,'Cat Name 13',13),
    (18,'Cat Name 14',13),
    (19,'Cat Name 15',13),
    (20,'Cat Name 16',13),
    (21,'Cat Name 17',13)//


CREATE FUNCTION hierarchy_connect_by_parent_eq_prior_id(value BIGINT) RETURNS INT
NOT DETERMINISTIC
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
        DECLARE _id BIGINT;
        DECLARE _parent_id BIGINT;
        DECLARE _next BIGINT;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET @id = NULL;

        SET _parent_id = @id;
        SET _id = -1;

        IF @id IS NULL THEN
                RETURN NULL;
        END IF;

        LOOP
                SELECT  MIN(id)
                INTO    @id
                FROM    `Category`
                WHERE   parent_id = _parent_id
                        AND id > _id;
                IF @id IS NOT NULL OR _parent_id = @start_with THEN
                        SET @level = @level + 1;
                        RETURN @id;
                END IF;
                SET @level := @level - 1;
                SELECT  id, parent_id
                INTO    _id, _parent_id
                FROM    `Category`
                WHERE   id = _parent_id;
        END LOOP;       
END//

SELECT  CONCAT(REPEAT('    ', level - 1), CAST(hi.id AS CHAR)) AS treeitem, hi.name, parent_id, level
FROM    (
        SELECT  hierarchy_connect_by_parent_eq_prior_id(id) AS id, @level AS level
        FROM    (
                SELECT  @start_with := 0,
                        @id := @start_with,
                        @level := 0
                ) vars, `Category`
        WHERE   @id IS NOT NULL
        ) ho
JOIN    `Category` hi
ON      hi.id = ho.id
```

Comment: It does work, however the thing with the `null` values was just a way to have the fk constraint working for the base categories. If I set `parent_id` default to `0`, it won't work due to the fk.